# How to initialize elements within ngFor in Angular2

Tags: angular, materialize, ngfor

I am using materialize css with angular 2 but without any components from github like angular2-material, i need to initialize select elements with material_select within a ngfor loop like

```
<div *ngFor = "let question from questionList">
    <div>
      // question
      <select [(value)] = "question.selectedAnswer" (change) = "selectChangeHandler(question.index)">
         <option value = "" disabled>Please select option<option>
         <option *ngFor = 'let questionDetail of questionDetails' value = "questionDetail.option">{{questionDetail.option}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
<div>
```

i tried to get the refrence of elements in ts file in ngAfterContentInit and ngAfterViewinit methods using ElementRef as well as Jquery but i get "undefined".

If i use setTimeout I can initialize the element but i wonder it is not best solution,
I also thought of writing init directive but not sure if it is final solution.

Could anybody provide a better solution to this?

Also how can i get change directive working with material_select as selectChangeHandler is not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: whatever you want to do is not clear !

Comment: Why are you *not* using angular2-materialize (or something similar).  I'm not 100% on this, but I believe that you'll need to use one of these wrappers if you don't want to deal with the hassle of rolling your own for the materialize JS functionality.

Comment: Sorry micronyks i was not able to put my question properly, What i need is to use materializecss select in my form which is in ngfor loop, i am trying to initalize it as $('select').material_select() but i do not get any select elements from form in either ngAfterContentInit or ngAfterViewInit. @Steve thanks for suggesting i have tried those but i want to experiment it without wrappers